# Cartpole - Number of layers and neurons - model hyperparameters

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

Can anyone please suggest me how to arrive to the best optimal values for number of layers, number of neurons parameters of the deep learning model in DDQN algorithm for cartpole problem.
As input and output neurons are 4 and 2 respectively for cartpole, are there any scientific reasons or maths behind choosing number of hidden layers and neurons in them.

I have followed this link to build reinforcement learning algorithm
https://pylessons.com/CartPole-reinforcement-learning/

Answer (score 1):

One of the best methods to find hyperparameter values is cross-validation. Empirically try different numbers of layers and different numbers of neurons and see which set of values has the best performance on the hold-out dataset.